# Node.js Route to specific div on page

Tags: html, node.js

I have a website with a page with different parts that I want my links on my navbar to go to when clicked.  I know in html you can use  to go to an Id on the page, but this won't work when on another page.  I use node.js for my back-end.

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
res.render("index");
});

app.get('/portfolio', function(req, res){
res.render('portfolio');
});
```

As you can see I have two routes, one for my homepage and one for my portfolio page.  On my homepage I use the html I said earlier to go to certain divs on my page.  However, on my portfolio page I can't use the same html and have to use my node routes to go to my index page.  Is there a way in node to have the page load on a certain div?

Answer (score 0):

hello my dear friend first of all you have to use a View Engine for rendering html pages and you can active it in express with `app.set('view engine', 'pug')` and with this way you can use id like this to open a certain div

`/portfolio/#firstDiv`